# PHP quit after I update an associative array

Tags: php, symfony

I have a really weird problem, I am doing a script that executes a symfony command.

Here it is :

```
<?php

$checkname = 'symfony_checker';
$sensu_ip = '192.168.13.000';
$port = 3002;

function write_to_sensu($json)
{
    echo('writing');
    try
    {
        $fp = fsockopen($sensu_ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
        if ($fp)
        {
            fwrite($fp, $json);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $E)
    {
    }
}

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/app/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

$input = new ArrayInput(array(
    'command'  => 'security:check',
    '--format' => 'json',

));
$output = new BufferedOutput();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);
$application->run($input, $output);

$payload = array(
'name' => $checkname,
"status" => 0
);

$payload = json_encode($payload);
$arr = json_decode($output->fetch());
$vulnerabilites = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $errors)
{
    $var = 0;
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    {
        if ($var == 1)
        {
            foreach ($error as $key => $one)
                array_push($vulnerabilites, $key);
        }
        $var++;
    }
}
$vulnerabilites = implode(' ', $vulnerabilites);
$payload['output'] = 'Vulnerabilities found : ' . $vulnerabilites;
dump($vulnerabilites);
write_to_sensu($payload);
```

Problem is that the program leave at the line :

```
$payload['output'] = 'Vulnerabilities found : ' . $vulnerabilites;
```

If I comment this line the code continue fine and goes to my function write to sensu. 
If I just update $payload['output'] with a random string it doesn't work either.

Every time I try to update payload, the program quit! Anywhere in the code.

Have any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting `$payload` into a string with the line

```
$payload = json_encode($payload);
```

so you cannot use it as an array anymore. Either assign the result of `json_encode()` to another variable, or update your array before the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You've already encoded your array to JSON before you attempt to add the vulnerabilities. So you're treating a string as an associative array.

You just need to move your line

`$payload = json_encode($payload);`

to after this line:

`$payload['output'] = 'Vulnerabilities found : ' . $vulnerabilites;`